# Rails routing constraints being ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am attempting to create a route that allows:

```
GET /locations           # locations#index
...
GET /locations/:id       # locations#show
GET /locations/:regions  # get locations by one or more region codes (e.g. 'MN+WI')
```

My routes:

```
resources :locations
# allow one or more, 2-character region codes (mixed case; comma or plus delimited)
get "/locations/:regions/" => "locations#index", :constraints => {:regions=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}[\+\,]?/}
root 'locations#index'
```

When I attempt to connect to `http://localhost:3000/locations/MN+WI`, I get an error that reads `Couldn't find Location with id=MN+WI` highlighting this part of the locations_controller:

```
def set_location
  @location = Location.find(params[:id])
end
```

For some reason, the constraint isn't being matched, leading to an invalid attempt to identify the resource by a numeric value.

What am I missing?

** edit **

locations#index action:

```
# GET /locations
# GET /locations.json
def index
  @locations = Location.order('name')
  @locations = Location.for_regions(params[:regions]) if params[:regions].present?
  @json = @locations.to_gmaps4rails
end
```

I rearranged the routes:

```
# allow one or more, 2-character region codes (mixed case; comma or plus delimited)
get "/locations/:regions/" => "locations#index", :constraints => {:regions=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}[\+\,]?/}
resources :locations
root 'locations#index'
```

Success:

- `http://localhost:3000/locations/1`
- `http://localhost:3000/locations/MN`

Failure:

- `http://localhost:3000/locations/MN+WI` (same error as above)

Comment: Mind posting your locations#index action? Also, have you tried moving the resource route line after the locations/:region line?

Answer (score 1):

The routes are serched from top to bottom, and the first route found gets fired. So your `get '/locations/:id' => 'locations#show'` route from the `resources :locations` group takes precedense before your constrain.

So the general rule for routes is that you should put more specific routes higher then more common ones.

In this case you need to move that route up and put it before the resources.